# Kotlin - How to get KClass<*> annotation parameter from annotation processor

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations

I have the following annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class Model(
    val owner: KClass<*>,
    val consumer: KClass<*>
)

@Model(DataOwner::class, DataConsumer::class)
interface Student {
    val name: String
    val group: Group
}
```

I need to get the value of `owner` and `consumer` in my annotation processor.

I've tried this approach:

```
private inline fun <reified T> findAnnotationValue(
    element: Element,
    annotationClass: KClass<*>,
    valueName: String
): T? {
    return element.annotationMirrors.map {
        it to it.annotationType.asElement() as TypeElement
    }.firstOrNull { (_, element) ->
        element.qualifiedName.contentEquals(annotationClass.qualifiedName)
    }?.let { (mirror, _) ->
        extractValue(mirror, valueName)
    }
}

private inline fun <reified T> extractValue(
    annotationMirror: AnnotationMirror,
    valueName: String
): T? {
    return annotationMirror.elementValues.toList()
        .firstOrNull { (key, _) ->
            key.simpleName.contentEquals(valueName)
        }?.let { (_, value) ->
            value.value as T
        }
}


val ownerClass: KClass<*> = findAnnotationValue(
    element,
    Model::class,
    "owner"
)
```

But it gave me this error:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType cannot be cast to kotlin.reflect.KClass
```

I also tried this:

```
val ownerClass: KClass<*> = element.getAnnotation(Model::class.java).owner
```

But it gave me this error:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: javax.lang.model.type.MirroredTypeException: Attempt to access Class object for TypeMirror inc.ahmedmourad.systems.tutors.domain.model.DataOwner
```

*`inc.ahmedmourad.systems.tutors.domain.model.DataOwner` is the `owner` value passed to the annotation.*

So this's where i'm stuck right now, any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the reason the second approach doesn't work:

> [The annotation returned by this method could contain **an element whose value is of type Class. This value cannot be returned directly: information necessary to locate and load a class (such as the class loader to use) is not available, and the class might not be loadable at all.** Attempting to read a Class object by invoking the relevant method on the returned annotation will result in a MirroredTypeException, from which the corresponding TypeMirror may be extracted. Similarly, attempting to read a Class[]-valued element will result in a MirroredTypesException.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class))

which obviously applies to `KClass` as well.

So for classes in annotations you can only get a [`TypeMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html) (implemented in this case by [`Type.ClassType`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.kohsuke.sorcerer/sorcerer-javac/0.11/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type.ClassType.html), but that's an internal detail you shouldn't rely on) and not a `KClass`. Either by the first approach or

```
inline fun <reified T : Annotation> Element.getAnnotationClassValue(f: T.() -> KClass<*>) = try { 
    getAnnotation(T::class.java).f() 
    throw Exception("Expected to get a MirroredTypeException")
} catch (e: MirroredTypeException) {
    e.typeMirror
}
```

which can be used as

```
element.getAnnotationClassValue<Model> { owner }
```

and returns the `TypeMirror` for `DataOwner`.

Comment: What if we need the KClass of this value and not the TypeMirror. Is there anyway to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: You _could_ try to get the name using https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/ProcessingEnvironment.html and then `KClass` from the name. You are not supposed to do that and it will certainly fail if the class is not in the standard library (to be precise, not in the compiler's classpath, which is not at all the classpath you are compiling with). Again, because those `Class`es and `KClass`es don't exist yet. Just to repeat: you are not supposed to do that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just to be more specific, In my use case I using the type mirror works even with non standard classes e.x: `Intent` from android. the problem is that if i do this when the  type is `kotlin.String` the returned mirror type is `java.lang.String` and this should be `kotlin.String` cuz my library has to operate with kotlin. How can i get the name? using typeutils? or element utils?

Comment: Ah, those only care about Java. I think you may have to just maintain a mapping of types based on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types, unless that's in kotlin-reflect somewhere.

Comment: Very Much appreciated! thanks a lot @alexey-romanov. I thought that it might be somewhere a utility class that maps from java to kotlin like here https://github.com/Multifuchs/kmf/blob/master/kmf-kapt/bin/main/de/mf/kmf/kapt/types/Utils.kt but it seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using KSP then the solution can look something like this:

Using the experimental APIs and assuming the KClass you reference in the annotation is available:

```
resolver.getSymbolsWithAnnotation("com.example.Model")
    .map {
        val consumerType = try {
            it.getAnnotationsByType(Model::class).first().consumer
            null
        } catch (e: KSTypeNotPresentException) {
            e.ksType
        }
        val consumerDeclaration = consumerType!!.declaration as KSClassDeclaration // etc
    }
```

If you can't do this, then maintaining a KSP view of the annotation is more flexible:

```
resolver.getSymbolsWithAnnotation("com.example.Model")
    .map { ksAnnotated ->
        val args = ksAnnotated.annotations.first {
            it.shortName.asString() == "Model" && it.annotationType.resolve().declaration.qualifiedName?.asString() == "com.example.Model"
        }.arguments

        val consumerType = args.first { it.name?.asString() == "owner" }.value as KSType
        val consumerDeclaration = consumerType.declaration as KSClassDeclaration // etc 
    }
```